# How to change index based section common color in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Normally my screen display is like this:

[image]

When I use this code

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];

    [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    return headerView;
}
```

my output is like this:

[image]

My section index text is not visible. I know that the section header view add my custom view. I want to change section header color and also display index text.

@Khawar answer i get this output

[image]

Comment: Dude you haven't added a label to your header view. It's showing what ever you have given and that's a simple white header and nothing else.

Comment: why this is off-topic

Comment: Sorry @iDev, i did not understand you question earlier. Please see the updated answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is work 100% and you can change your index or header text color

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    view.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    // if you have index/header text in your tableview change your index text color 
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerIndexText = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    [headerIndexText.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

}
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the height for UITableView header.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 30.0;
}
```

If you only need to change the background color of section header while displaying section title, you don't need to create custom view for that. Custom view would overwrite your default header and your title would not be shown, unless you add custom UILabel in your custom view. Just use following `UITableView` delegate to change background color.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {
    view.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

See results before and after.

**----------------Before------------------**

[image]

**----------------After------------------**

[image]

Hope this fixes the issue.

Comment: Not at all dude :), got code and screenshot from my existing app ;). Just was not sure about your question yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give title for section...  Or you can use this method..

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UILabel *headerView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];
   [headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5]];
    headerView.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    return headerView;
}
```